# Support landscape for one fragment in ViewPager and TabLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, screen-orientation, android-tablayout

My app has a single Activity with a custom FragmentStatePagerAdapter with three fragments Using ViewPager and TabLayout. 
One of these fragments has support both landscape and portrait, the other two are fixed to portrait orientation.
Below is the code in fragments,

```
// Used by the fragment which supports Portrait only
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser) {
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}

//Used by the fragment which supports Portrait and lanscape
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser) {
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
    }
}
```

It is working fine when we try to navigate to tab(Full sensor) in portrait from other tab(portrait fixed). But when we try to navigate in landscape mode,
ViewPager loading wrong fragment(other than the selected tab) is loaded in the selected tab in landscape.